# ClearCase - How to list all checkout that may conflict with mine?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I am working on a script that will update a bunch of files in a given ClearCase folder. Before to start, I want to check in the script if any checkout that will be performed during the process may fail (because of another checkout). The script does not know the config spec in use.

The basic idea based on `cleartool lsco -rec` cannot work because of the many false-positive result (mostly, checkout done on a not selected branch, or unreserved checkout).

So the question is: **How can I list all file that I cannot checkout because of another checkout that will conflict with mine?**

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> "The basic idea based on `cleartool lsco -rec` cannot work"

Yet it should work.
You can compare `cleartool lsco -brtype abranch -me` and `cleartool lsco -brtype abranch` in order to see *other* checkouts done on the target branch, not by you.
You can `|grep -v` unreserved to trim out any unreserved checkout.
The end result is the list of files, checkout not by you, reserved.
You can then compare that list with the files your script has to modify.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a classic-UCM environment, this would generally not happen if you're not working in a shared stream. So, I'm going to assume you are working in base clearcase.

One way to check this would be to look at the version trees of the files you plan on checking out. However, to automate it, you would need to also know what branch you're working on.

For a single file:

Windows:

```
cleartool lsvtree {my file} | findstr CHECKEDOUT
```

Unix
    cleartool lsvtree {my file} | grep CHECKEDOUT

Any CHECKEDOUT returns on your branch (which may be /main if you're not doing parallel  development) would block you.

If you have a list of files, it would depend on how you want to process that list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have thought of this 'solution', however as you say it yourself, this requires to know the branch the user of the script is working on which is not the case.

Comment: Well, you could always use cleartool describe -fmt "%Vn\n" foo.c, but the issue with that is that you need to parse the output with something. If you need a Perl script, that can be arranged.